# Select2 change input name if tag is being submited

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

So I have the following select2:

```
productFamilySelect.select2({
            tags: true
        });
```

By default the name of the associated select element is `product_family_id`, so is there a way to change the name of the input to lets say `product_family_name`, if selected value if one that user entered? This is so, that I could in the backend for sure distinguish between an already existing value, and one that user thought of. Checking by id in the database does not really suit, as this value could actually be numeric in on itself.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging into select2 custom events I found a way:

firstly add createTag callback like so:

```
productFamilySelect.select2({
            tags: true,
            createTag: function (params) {
                var term = $.trim(params.term);

                if (term === '') {
                    return null;
                }
                return {
                    id: term,
                    text: term,
                    newTag: true
                }
            }
        });
```

Then, add the following listener:

```
productFamilySelect.on('select2:select', function (e) {
            if (e.params.data.newTag === true) {
                $(this).attr('name', 'product_family_name');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('name', 'product_family_id');
            }
        });
```

Seems a bit hacky, since it is outside the config of the actual select2 config, but well it dos the job :)